# jQuery's replaceWith() CSS alignment not same as exact same straight code

Tags: jquery, css, alignment, replacewith

This is a really weird issue I'm having and I'm not really sure what code to paste here because there's quite a lot so I'm really looking for theoretical solutions I guess.

Basically, I'm using jQuery's replaceWith() to add stuff to a box after a user logs in. It adds the exact same code as would be spat out by the php page (having checked a user has logged in). This was done so when they log in, jQuery adds their content but it should be exactly the same if they refresh or move to another page on the site.

This mostly works, except for a few form elements appearing to be out of alignment after jQuery replaces the content. After refreshing the page, they are aligned the way they should be.

Any ideas what might be happening? I've gone through Chrome's dev tools looking at the CSS margins on these elements and their surrounding elements and the margins/padding etc. are exactly the same but display weird until refreshed!!

This is driving me nuts - has anyone seen this behavior before?

Cheers,

Scott

Screenshots might help -
[image: jQuery - incorrect]
[image: PHP - correct]

Here's an example of the code:

```
<?php
    echo '<div id="accountpanel">
            <div id="selectclientbox">
              <form id="formSelectClient" action="" onsubmit="return false;">
                  <select id="selectClient">
                      <option>Client 1</option>
                      <option>Client 2</option>
                      <option>Client 3</option>
                      <option>Client 4</option>
                  </select>
                  <select id="selectAttribute">
                      <option>Change ID</option>
                      <option>Change Userame</option>
                      <option>Change Password</option>
                      <option>Change Name</option>
                      <option>Change Email Address</option>
                  </select>
                  <input id="changeDetail" class="coolbox" type="text" size="38" maxlength="128" />
                  <input id="updatebtn" type="button" value="update" onclick="updatedetail()" />
              </form>
              <form id="formUpdateClient" action="" onsubmit="return false;">

                  <section>
                      <label for="changeCurrency">Currency</label><input id="changeCurrency" class="text" type="text" maxlength="1" />

                      <input id="updatebtn2" type="button" value="update" onclick="updatecost()" />
                  </section>
              </form>
          </div>
    </div>';
?>

<div id="accountpanel2">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#accountpanel2').replaceWith('<div id="accountpanel2">' + 
                '<div id="selectclientbox">' +
              '<form id="formSelectClient" action="" onsubmit="return false;">' +
                  '<select name="">' +
                      '<option>Client 1</option>' +
                      '<option>Client 2</option>' +
                      '<option>Client 3</option>' +
                      '<option>Client 4</option>' +
                  '</select>' +
                  '<select name="">' +
                      '<option>Change ID</option>' +
                      '<option>Change Userame</option>' +
                      '<option>Change Password</option>' +
                      '<option>Change Name</option>' +
                      '<option>Change Email Address</option>' +
                  '</select>' +
                  '<input id="changeDetail" class="coolbox" type="text" size="38" maxlength="128" />' +
                  '<input id="updatebtn" type="button" value="update" onclick="updatedetail()" />' +
              '</form>' +
              '<form id="formUpdateClient" action="" onsubmit="return false;">' +

                  '<section>' +
                      '<label for="changeCurrency">Currency</label><input id="changeCurrency" class="text" type="text" maxlength="1" />' +
                      '<input id="updatebtn2" type="button" value="update" onclick="updatecost()" />' +
                  '</section>' +
              '</form>' +
          '</div>');
</script>
```

Comment: May be you use any js that customize your form's inputs?

Comment: I haven't used js to modify any CSS except fadeIn() on the whole accountPanel DIV so I don't think that's the answer. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you link to the site? Without a link, it's very unlikely anyone will be able to help.

Comment: Not easily since it's a login system and the problem only appears on administrator accounts :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looking at your example code I see a big difference between the HTML you are using to render the page and the code being "injected".

In the JavaScript string you have constructs that look like this (this is just an example, probably not the exact line that is causing the problem):

```
'<select name="">' +
  '<option>Change ID</option>' +
  '<option>Change Userame</option>' +
  '<option>Change Password</option>' +
  '<option>Change Name</option>' +
  '<option>Change Email Address</option>' +
'</select>' +
```

And in the HTML it looks like this:

```
   <select name="">
     <option>Change ID</option>
     <option>Change Userame</option>
     <option>Change Password</option>
     <option>Change Name</option>
     <option>Change Email Address</option>
  </select>
```

The result to the parser is two very different thing because the non JavaScript has a significant amount of whitespace and a carrage return + line feed between each element.

This is the reverse of what I described -- it seems you need the white space to get it to look right.

There are two ways to solve this that come to mind right away.  1) Store your HTML templates in a script tag.  I like this because it makes them easy to edit and you don't have deal with lots of quotes and plus signs on every line. or 2) Add at least one space to the end of each line before the end quote and plus.

---

Yes, I've seen this many years ago, tracked it down to a space between a tag end and a tag start.  Should not matter, but did.

I had something like this

```
..</tag1> <tag2>...
```

And changed it to

```
..</tag1><tag2>...
```

It solved the problem.

I seem to remember this was more common with IE and list elements -- but I could be remembering wrong.

Comment: Fantastic idea, I'll check and get back to you!

Comment: I really thought this was the answer as it totally makes sense but unfortunately it isn't. Each line of HTML to be inserted inside the replaceWith is on its own line with no whitespace. Back to the drawing board :( Thanks though. Any more ideas?

Comment: Can you show the html (view source) inserted via php and the javascript?

Comment: I don't think I can because when you use "view source" it fetches essentially a new copy of the site (same as a refresh) so you can't diff the two outputs. I tried this and diff said they were identical (except I know different because I've used fadeIn() so some elements have inline style tags for "display:block" where I originally have them all in an external CSS). I tried to use chrome's dev tools to copy the current html but it wouldn't let me select more than one line. Any ideas how else to get the live code?

Comment: Ah, I wanted to see the view source of the php and then the javascript -- I know we can't view source after the change (tho chrome will show you some stuff in the "inspect element" page.

Comment: Sorry I haven't replied, I've been crazy busy! What I'll do then is make a file containing the php, the javascript and the necessary CSS and link it here (just so if you still feel like helping, you don't need to sieve through loads. I'll try and post a link to it soon, or append it to my original question. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hey, I've super-simplified it down to the problem and haven't even included any CSS and still the problem persists.

http://pastebin.com/SvdSVGnQ

Comment: Ahh! Thank you! I feel a bit stupid now, that actually seems quite obvious looking at the code now. My Javascript is basically spitting out one big long HTML line.. I'm a little confused by what you mean with "Store your HTML templates in a script tag". Do you mean something like (but obviously not exactly) <script type='text/javascript' src='/path/to/template.html'></script> ? I tried Googling but maybe I'm not using the right keywords.